# How to sort contours in EMGUCV/C# from left to right?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

How do we sort contours in EMGUCV 4.5 from left to right? There is no sorting function defined in the library.

Has anyone tried sorting contours in the new version of EMGUCV ?

Answer (score 1):

Have extracted the bounding rect and sorted using linq. See below

```
    static void Sort(Mat img, VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours)
    {
        List<Rectangle> rects= new List<Rectangle>();

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
        {
            var rect = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contours[i]);
            rects.Add(rect);
            CvInvoke.Rectangle(img, rect, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 0), 3);
            CvInvoke.Imshow("img", img);
            CvInvoke.WaitKey();
        }

        var rectList = rects.Distinct().OrderBy(r => r.Left).ThenBy(r 
             => r.Top).ToList();
    }
```